# need javascript to call hidden value in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

i have 2 dropdown list , warehouse and location(called as subwarehouse in my coding).

the warehouse is the parent and location is the child.
what i want is that eg, when a user clicks on warehouse ddl,
this results will show:

- Singapore
- Malaysia
- Thailand

as user clicks on [singapore],
location will show:

- Woodlands
- Sembawang

**how do i make my location show results of warehouse selected?

```
 function einv_generateWarehouseDropdown($warehouse,$field,$subwarehouse)
    {
        //connect to database
        base_connectDatabase();
        echo "<select id=\"".$field."\" name=\"".$field."\"  style=\"width:300px\" onChange=\"getSubjDesc(this.value);showSubWarehouseDetails(this.value)\" onfocus=\"getSubjDesc(this.value);showSubWarehousehouseDetails(this.value)\">";

        //if (isset($warehouse)) {
        if (isset($warehouse) && ($warehouse != "")) {
            $warehousename = einv_getWarehouseDetail($warehouse);
            echo "<option value=\"". $warehouse ."\">". $warehousename['einv_wh_name'] ."</option>";
        } else {
            $warehouse = 0;
        }

        $getWarehouseSQL = base_executeSQL("SELECT * FROM einv_warehouse where einv_wh_id<>" . $warehouse . " 
        ORDER BY einv_wh_name");
        while($warehousedata_row = base_fetch_array($getWarehouseSQL)){
            if (base_num_rows($getWarehouseSQL)!= 0) {
                echo "<option value=\"". $warehousedata_row['einv_wh_id'] ."\">". $warehousedata_row['einv_wh_name']."</option>";
            }
        }
        echo  "</select>";

        $subwarehouse = "";
        $getSubWarehouseSQL = base_executeSQL("SELECT * FROM einv_subwarehouse  ORDER BY einv_whs_name");
        while($subwarehousedata_row = base_fetch_array($getSubWarehouseSQL)){
            if (base_num_rows($getSubWarehouseSQL)!= 0) {
                $subwarehouse.="<input type=hidden name='lstsubj_DESC_".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_wh_id']."[]' id='lstsubj_DESC_".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_id']."' value='".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_id']."|||".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_name']."'>\n";
                //$subwarehouse.="<input type=hidden name='lstcomp_DESC_".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_wh_id']."[]' id='lstcomp_DESC_".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_id']."' value='".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_id']."'>\n";
            }
        }
        echo $subwarehouse;

        //close the database
        base_closeDatabase();
    }

    function einv_generateSubWarehouseDropdown($subwarehouse,$field)
    {
        //connect to database
        base_connectDatabase();

        $subwarehouse = NULL;
        echo "<select id=\"".$field."\" name=\"".$field."\"  style=\"width:200px\">";
    //  onChange=\"getSubjDesc(this.value);showSubWarehouseDetails(this.value)\" onfocus=\"getSubjDesc(this.value);showSubWarehousehouseDetails(this.value)\">";


        if (isset($subwarehouse))
        {
            $subwarehousename = einv_getSubWarehouseDetail($subwarehouse);
            echo "<option value=\"". $subwarehouse ."\">". $subwarehousename['einv_whs_name'] ."</option>";
            //$subwarehouse.="<input type=hidden name='lstsubj_DESC_".$subwarehouse."' id='lstsubj_DESC_".$subwarehouse."' value='".$subwarehousename['einv_whs_name']."'>\n";
            //$subwarehouse.="<input type=hidden name='lstcomp_DESC_".$subwarehouse."' id='lstcomp_DESC_".$subwarehouse."' value='".$subwarehousename['einv_whs_id']."'>\n";
        }elseif(!isset($subwarehouse))
        {
            $subwarehouse = 0;
        }
        echo "SELECT * FROM einv_subwarehouse where einv_whs_id<>" . $subwarehouse . " 
        ORDER BY einv_whs_name";
        $getSubWarehouseSQL = base_executeSQL("SELECT * FROM einv_subwarehouse where einv_whs_id<>". $subwarehouse . " 
        ORDER BY einv_whs_name");
             while($subwarehousedata_row = base_fetch_array($getSubWarehouseSQL))
             if (base_num_rows($getSubWarehouseSQL)!= 0)
             {
                 echo "<option value=\"". $subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_id'] ."\">". $subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_name']."</option>";
                // $subwarehouse.="<input type=hidden name='lstsubj_DESC_".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_id']."' id='lstsubj_DESC_".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_id']."' value='".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_name']."'>\n";
                // $subwarehouse.="<input type=hidden name='lstcomp_DESC_".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_id']."' id='lstcomp_DESC_".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_id']."' value='".$subwarehousedata_row['einv_whs_id']."'>\n";
             }
        echo  "</select>";
        echo $subwarehouse;


        //close the database
        base_closeDatabase();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably need [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) for that chained feature. A simple method for doing it without ajax is using [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attribute:

```
<select id="parent">
    <option value="1">Parent 1</option>
</select>

<select id="child">
    <option data-parentid="1">Child 1 from Parent 1</option>
</select>
```

Then you perform a `change` event to *show* or *hide* the desired child options.

Code omitted for brevity. Check it out on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwdengmz/).

By the way, this is just an example. You have to implement it on your code. Good luck.

Comment: @HishamMuhd any problem please let me know.

Comment: hey man this is working fine except for one thing. i dont know how to put it exactly in words.. as i click on parent 1, 2 child options - child 1 from 1 and child 2 from 1. thats fine but when i change and click on the parent 2, it lists out the child options from parent 2 fine but the first option non listed will be child 1 from 1. how do i make it that this doesnt show?

Comment: simply put i just want purely child option values to be shown as i click on a parent option @DontVoteMeDown